# C# - SQLite select distinct rows then return as list of string

Tags: c#, sqlite

How can I return a List to my query:

```
public List<string> GetLocalQuestionChoicesGroups(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(localDBPath, "Travue.db")))
                {
                    var groups = connection.Query<string>("SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM QuestionChoice WHERE GroupName IS NOT NULL AND QuestionId=?", Id).ToList();
                    return groups;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("Error", ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I am getting an error:

> 'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method 'SQLiteConnection.Query(string, params object[])'

Comment: SQLiteConnection.Query<T> method needs T which has default constructor. [Read here](http://www.rbdocumentation.com/html/ee6c5c5e-365a-bd25-fbc9-63c601b3c1b8.htm). String type in C# does not have default constructor [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Are there any ways to return a list of string from the query?

Comment: You can use SQLiteCommand to to execute the query and return DataReader with one column. You can iterate thru the DataReader to read the column data row by row and populate the collection of strings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0#methods